Оформление QCalendarWidget PyQt

def get_stylesheet(self):
        return """
            QWidget {
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: black;
            }
            QCalendarWidget {
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                border-radius: 5px;
                background-color: white;
            }
            QPushButton {
                padding: 10px;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 5px;
                background-color: #007BFF;
                color: white;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin: 10px 0;
            }
            QPushButton:hover {
                background-color: #0056b3;
            }
        """

Добавил в интерфейс виджет, однако при запуске с ide календарь выглядит норм, а при запуске из консоли все ломается, для календаря в этом окне также использую stylesheet, приведенный ниже
Пытался перебрать все стили, но ничего не меняется, помогите

как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка
